# Deploying Symfony 2.5.7 to heroku cloud - Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle' not found

Tags: symfony, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony app to heroku and am following the [Deploying to Heroku](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/heroku.html) tutorial.

However, when I `push` my code to my heroku app, heroku fails to compile my app and I get the following message after the packages from `composer.json` get downloaded:

> Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle' not found in /tmp/build_45216c70c70215d5009d6aaa12fb90c1/app/AppKernel.php on line 16
>
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]
>     An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

This is the content of my `composer.json`:

```
...,
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "~2.1",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "~3.3",
    "symfony/serializer": "~2.6"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
    }
}
```

When I install the vendors on my local machine, I can find the `DoctrineBundle` class in `vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/DoctrineBundle.php`, so I don't understand this error :-(....

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a long-standing issue in Symfony, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12784

You need to upgrade Symfony to 2.5.8 or newer, or 2.6.1 or newer.

Also make sure you've set `SYMFONY_ENV` to `prod` in `heroku config`.